# Nano syntax highlighting in Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: c, macos, terminal, syntax-highlighting, nano

How to enable syntax highlighting for nano in Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

According to what I found so far on Google is that it has got to do with `/.nanorc` file. I have no idea how to get it or make it?

When I try to find `nano` in my terminal this is what I get:

```
Notra:~ Sukhvir$ whereis nano
/usr/bin/nano
```

According to what I found on Internet this is the file I need to edit:

```
~/.nanorc
```

But how do I get to it/how to open it/if I don't have it then how to make it?

I am a bit new to programming folks, so step-by-step instructions will be highly appreciated.

I need it for `C` mainly.

According to what I found online, I have to paste this into the `.nanorc` file:

```
include "/usr/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc"
include "/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"
```

However this will not work because there is no such directory as `/usr/share/nano`.

I also just did `ls /usr/share/` and according to the results there is no `nano` in that directory. Is this a Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) issue or an issue on my Mac?

Comment: You can edit the `~/.nanorc` by typing `nano ~/.nanorc`. Then add whatever you need to it to get highlight syntax working -- I assume that you've found the correct syntax in your Google searches for this.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply CanSpice , but like i just mentioned in my edited post the code I found online wont work because /usr/share/nano directory doen't exist on my mac.

Any modifications I have to make to that code ???

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are some steps to help you out.

1. Create a new directory in `/usr/local/share/` called 'nano' like this:

> mkdir /usr/local/share/nano

2. Now, using nano, make a nano resource file for your C syntax like this:

> nano /usr/local/share/nano/c.nanorc`

3. Now put your C code highlighting in this file and save it. Here is a link to some possible C syntax highlighting:

> http://code.google.com/p/nanosyntax/source/browse/trunk/syntax-nanorc/c.nanorc

4. Save that file and now open your user’s nano resource file by typing:

> nano ~/.nanorc

5. In this file, add a reference to the c.nanorc file you just made like this:

> include "/usr/local/share/nano/c.nanorc"

6. Save your user resource file.

Now, when you open up C files, you should see syntax highlighting. You can add additional syntax highlighting for different types of files using the same method. Just add more lines to your `~/.nanorc` file.

Note that depending on your user permissions, you may have to precede some of the above commands with sudo and then enter your root password.

Comment: I had to upgrade nano from 2.0.6 to 2.2.6-- see the answer below

Answer (score 68):

On Mac, [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (`brew`) will allow you to easily upgrade [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) to a newer version than the one that came with Mac OSX.

Install `brew`, then install a new version of `nano` from the Terminal.

```sh
brew install nano
```

Installing this way includes the `/usr/local/share/nano` folder containing the default syntax highlight files. See also the `extra` subdirectory.

To enable all default syntaxes, [add a wildcard include](https://askubuntu.com/a/90026) to your [`~/.nanorc`](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html).

```
include "/usr/local/share/nano/*.nanorc"
```

For Apple Silicon (M1), the path is under `/opt/homebrew/`:

```
include "/opt/homebrew/share/nano/*.nanorc"
```

Comment: This oneline is bash specific!

Comment: Awesome! Also, I had to add this `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to my `.zshrc` to get it to work.

Comment: Great instructions. I ran into a problem when running ```brew install nano```. The error: ```Error: SHA1 mismatch```. I simply removed the incomplete file (```rm -rf /dir/file```) that was located here: ```/Library/Caches/Homebrew/nano-2.2.6.tar.gz```. Did ```nano -V``` to get the version of nano already on my machine (2.0.6), then tried ```brew install nano``` again. Once I restarted my terminal it nano had been updated to 2.2.6. Thanks!

Comment: Just to note that sometime prior to September 2017 the `homebrew/dupes` tap has been deprecated and the formulae (including nano) moved into the main repository, so a simple `brew install nano` is all that is required now.

Comment: @Sheharyar that is what I had to do to get this working as well.

Answer (score 11):

I'm maintaining a bunch of fairly accurate syntax definitions for nano here: https://github.com/craigbarnes/nanorc. The default "example" definitions that come with nano are *very* poor quality, as are those mentioned above.

Comment: +1 for very nice collection of definitions. Can you comment on how your collection compares with the one [here](https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc)?

Comment: @CraigBarnes states "I am no longer maintaining this repo" There is an alternate repo of nanorc in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19582587/1020470) and [Scopatz repo of nanorc](https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc) are good IMO; I use them on Mac.

Answer (score 4):

**2018 Update**

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) so you can download latest version of nano
2. `brew install nano`
3. `nano ~/.nanorc`
4. Add file path to homebrew nano's syntax highlighting

   - (updated with new langs such as JS)
   - `include "/usr/local/Cellar/nano/*/share/nano/*.nanorc"`

1st `*` allows us to include whichever version of nano you have, instead of 2.9.3 (for example). Second `*` includes all .nanorc files so we have syntax highlighting for all languages that are included!

---

**Testing**

```
cd ~/Desktop
touch test.py
touch test.js
nano test.py
nano test.js
```

---

**Further .nanorc Customization**

I added "set mouse" and "set smooth" to my .nanorc file as well. This allows for mouse use and smooth scrolling. Find more info on these options by running `nano --help`.

---

**Updated Syntax Highlighting**

https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc has "improved" syntax highlighting, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

## Easy flow:

> brew update && brew install nano

After new nano is installed add this line to `~/.nanorc` to enable syntax highlighting for all provided syntaxes:

> include /usr/local/share/nano/*.nanorc

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Mark Mikofski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020470/mark-mikofski) in the comment to another answer, this is the maintained repo for `nanorc` files:

> https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc